# Multiplying $3\times 1$ and $1\times 3$ matrices together

Tags: linear-algebra

Can someone explain how to multiply these two matrices?

$\left( \begin{array}{ccc}1  \\ 3\\1
 \end{array} \right) \cdot \left( \begin{array}{ccc}-1&0&2 
 \end{array} \right) $

I thought that the solution would just be the dot product between the two, giving us $(1)$, but the solution is actually $\left( \begin{array}{ccc}-1&0&2\\-3&0&6\\-1&0&2
 \end{array} \right)$.

Comment: This is not row times column, but column times row.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're multiplying a $3 \times 1$ matrix ${\bf a} = (a_i)$ by a $1 \times 3$ matrix ${\bf b}^\top = (b_j)$, which gives a $3 \times 3$ matrix ${\bf a} {\bf b}^\top$, namely the one with $(i, j)$ entry $a_i b_j$. This is the *outer product* of ${\bf a}, {\bf b}$ and is sometimes denotes by ${\bf a} \otimes {\bf b}$.

If you multiplied them in the reverse order, you'd get a $1 \times 1$ matrix ${\bf b}^\top {\bf a}$, with sole entry $$\sum_{i = 1}^3 a_i b_i,$$ which is just the *inner product* of ${\bf a}, {\bf b}$. Notice that ${\bf b}^\top {\bf a} = \operatorname{tr}({\bf a}{\bf b}^\top)$.

Answer (score 1):

The result matrix is $c_{ij}=\sum_{k=1}^n a_{ik}b_{kj}$

"Its the mantra line-by-column" take the first line, in this case the first element is the element 1 and multiply it by the first column element -1.

first line * second column 1*0

first line * third column 1*2

then pass to second line and repeat

second line* first column, and so on

Comment: @VMMF Please don't make cosmetic edits on (nine year) old posts. It moves them to the active question queue and distracts people like me who follow that queue.

Answer (score 0):

For multiplying A and B , AB will have no of rows as of A and no of colums as of B